# use complete to fill in custom range for each group

Tags: dplyr

I have a dataframe with different sites that were sampled in different years. I want to use the complete function so that I have one row for each year between the earliest and last years the sites were sampled. So, for site A below, there would be one row for each year between 2007 and 2017.

Example:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(site = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5),
                 year = floor(runif(15, 2000, max = 2018))) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  arrange(site, year) 

   site year
1     A 2007
2     A 2011
3     A 2014
4     A 2017
5     B 2001
6     B 2007
7     B 2008
8     B 2010
9     C 2004
10    C 2005
11    C 2011
12    C 2014
13    C 2017
```

I have tried using `complete(site, year)`, but then each site has a row for all possible years (i.e., the years for site A span 2001 to 2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
dplyr::reframe(df, year = min(year):max(year), .by = site)
```

Output:

```
   site year
1     A 2005
2     A 2006
3     A 2007
4     A 2008
5     A 2009
6     A 2010
7     A 2011
8     A 2012
9     A 2013
10    A 2014
11    A 2015
12    A 2016
13    B 2002
14    B 2003
15    B 2004
16    B 2005
17    B 2006
18    B 2007
19    B 2008
20    B 2009
21    B 2010
22    B 2011
23    B 2012
24    B 2013
25    C 2004
26    C 2005
27    C 2006
28    C 2007
29    C 2008
30    C 2009
31    C 2010
32    C 2011
33    C 2012
34    C 2013
35    C 2014
36    C 2015
37    C 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

`complete()` takes all possible values in a column into regard. Since you
are interested only in the site-specific range one solution is, to split
the data frame into separate data frames by site, apply `complete()` and
bind the data frames back together.

Here is how we can do that:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Recreating data from question
set.seed(42)
df <-
  data.frame(site = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 5),
             year = floor(runif(15, 2000, max = 2018))) %>%
  distinct() |>
  arrange(site, year)

# split, complete, bind
df2 <- 
  df |>
  group_by(site) |>
  group_split() |>
  map(mutate, year = factor(year, levels = min(year):max(year))) |>
  map(complete, site, year) |>
  map(arrange, site, year) |>
  list_rbind() |> 
  mutate(year = year |> as.character() |> as.numeric())

df2
#> # A tibble: 37 × 2
#>    site   year
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 A      2005
#>  2 A      2006
#>  3 A      2007
#>  4 A      2008
#>  5 A      2009
#>  6 A      2010
#>  7 A      2011
#>  8 A      2012
#>  9 A      2013
#> 10 A      2014
#> # ℹ 27 more rows

# Check that min/max years are site-specific
df2 |> 
  group_by(site) |> 
  summarise(min_year = min(year), max_year = max(year))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   site  min_year max_year
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 A         2005     2016
#> 2 B         2002     2013
#> 3 C         2004     2016
```